# Bridge network and bond interface taking same ip

Tags: keep-alive, bridge, openstack-neutron

I have a HA (High available) openstack controller with a Newton version. Openstack controller OAM management network uses bond0 interface with the network ip address 172.28.252.198 (primary). I also have keepalived configuration in the system and my controller servers are using 172.28.252.200 as VIP address (as secondary). I am using bridge network system. After creating provider network (which is the same network with OAM: 172.28.252.192/26) on dashboard, the bridge interface brq88cc4ef1-0f is created on the controller.
I observed that the ip address <172.28.250.198> is assigned on both bridge(brq88cc4ef1-0f) and a bond0 interface. In this case i cannot access to my controller server. I think the problem is related with ip conflict on the interface. Is it possible to use openstack OAM management network and provider network in a same subnet? Could you please help me about it. How can i make the system create network only on a single interface?

```
31: brq88cc4ef1-0f: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 1e:bb:ff:aa:90:11 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.28.252.198/26 brd 172.28.250.255 scope global brq88cc4ef1-0f
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 172.28.252.200/32 brd 172.28.250.200 scope global brq88cc4ef1-0f
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

36: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:36:9f:54:59:72 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.28.252.198/26 brd 172.28.250.255 scope global bond0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```